# mySQL SELECT query is changing the value to 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple database named 'schedule' that holds two entries: `desiredTemp` and `currentTemp`. For demonstration purposes, let's say that both `desiredTemp` and `currentTemp` hold the value of `77`.

I wrote a simple php script to retrieve these values:

current_temp.php:

```
<?php
    include 'session.php';
    $query = "SELECT currentTemp FROM schedule";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $currentTemp = mysql_result($result,0);
    echo $currentTemp;
    mysql_close();
?>
```

to retrieve `currentTemp`

desired_temp.php:

```
<?php
    include 'session.php';
    $query = "SELECT desiredTemp FROM schedule";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $desiredTemp = mysql_result($result,0);
    echo $desiredTemp;
    mysql_close();
?>
```

to retrieve `desiredTemp` (assume I have all credentials accounted for)

Running the script from a browser to retrieve `currentTemp` works fine, but when running the script to retrieve `desiredTemp`, the value in the database gets set to `0` and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I have another script that updates `desiredTemp` from a POST value, but this script shouldn't be running in the files above. This file is listed below as "update_temp.php"

EDIT: any time I run either desired_temp.php or current_temp.php, the value of `desiredTemp` in the database gets reset to `0`

Both table entries were initialized the same way at the same time. The values are both INTs with length of 11 (arbitrary)

Any help as to why this is happening is much appreciated

EDIT: here are the rest of the files used in the project:

index.php:

```
<?php
    include 'session.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM schedule";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $desiredTemp = $row['desiredTemp'];
?>
Hello, World!
<br>
Desired temperature is: <?php echo $desiredTemp; ?>

<form name="myForm" action="update_temp.php" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="desiredTemp">Change Desired Temperature</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desiredTemp" name="desiredTemp" placeholder="Enter new temp" maxlength="10">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
<?php mysql_close(); ?>
```

update_temp.php:

```
<?php
    include 'session.php';

    $desiredTemp = $_POST['desiredTemp'];
    $query = "UPDATE schedule SET desiredTemp='$desiredTemp'";
    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();
    header( 'Location: index.php' );
?>
```

session.php:

```
<?php
    $dbusername="****";
    $dbpassword="****";
    $database="****";
    mysql_connect('****',$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
 ?>
```

Comment: Please post the update part as that is most likely what changes the value - a simple select as shown won't!

Comment: Your select statement isn't changing the value. You're looking in the wrong place. Post more code, find anything that relates to updating the table value.

Comment: Why does one file include `api/session.php`, and the other include just `session.php` ? Please post the contents of these files (obscure the actual credentials if you're worried about them)

Comment: Is the 'another script' you mentioned can update desiredTemp successfully? Please also post that code we could have some clues.

Comment: Thank you everyone for replying. @jcsanyi - `api/session.php` and `session.php` are the same file...I had just forgotten to remove the directory before posting it up. @ydoow - the update script is the `update_temp.php` posted at the very end